# Pick DB extremely slow tcl queries

Tags: multivalue, pick

In our PICK database all of the sudden select/list/sort statements have become extremely slow in one particular file. At first I thought it was a file resize issue but I've resized the file and no luck. Any ideas or suggestions?

i.e `SELECT <FILENAME> WITH LOAD.DATE = "TODAY"`

This type of select would almost be instant and out of nowhere that will take over 5 minutes to actually process.

Any ideas will help.

Comment: Hey Sergio, guessing you mean this is a D3 system and not an app running d3.js? What operating system is it running on? Can you post the contents of the LOAD.DATE dict that the select is using? Also, do you happen to have any indices on the file?

Comment: Hi @Mike-Wright, thanks for your response. Yes, this is a D3 system running on Redhat distro.  AC.. ATTRIBUTE-NAME TY CW STRUC INPUT-CONVERSION CORRELATIVE OUTPUT-CONVERSION

  63 LOAD.DATE      L  10       D                            D2/